# Fetching Title Attributes from Multiple Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a site with lots of buttons. Each of these has a Title Attribute. I would like to insert the text from the Title Attribute into the Button Text as a line underneath the Button Text, like a caption.

See below for an example of my buttons.

```html
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 1">Button Text 1</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 2">Button Text 2</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 3">Button Text 3</button>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to fetch the Title Attribute text and append it to the Button Text so I didn't have to update all the buttons manually.

I tried something like:

```js
var title = $( "button" ).attr( "title" );
$( "div" ).text( title );
```

But `.attr()` only fetches the Title Attribute from the first Button element and none of the rest.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `each` to iterate over each `.btn`. For example, if you want to append the title text to the existing button:

```js
$('.btn').each(function() {
  $(this).text( $(this).text() + ' --- ' + $(this).prop('title') );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 1">Button Text 1</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 2">Button Text 2</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 3">Button Text 3</button>
```

Comment: OP wants to append the title to the button text, not to the document

Comment: Thanks-- how would you insert the Title Text into the actual Button, below/after the Button Text?

Comment: @JeremyGrab Your current code shows you trying to insert text into a div: `$( "div" ).text( title );` What div is that? If that's what you want, all you need to do is select the appropriate div and set its text.

Comment: I was planning on putting <div></div> tags (maybe with a specific id) inside the button text to show the title. I didn't get too far.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely don't need jQuery for this. In fact, you don't even need JavaScript

```css
button[title]:after {
  content: attr(title);
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 1">Button Text 1</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 2">Button Text 2</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 3">Button Text 3</button>
```

---

If you're still keen on a JS solution, here's an example iterating each `<button>` (that has a `title` attribute) and appending a new `<div>` element containing the `title` attribute text.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[title]').forEach(btn => {
  let caption = document.createElement('div')
  caption.textContent = btn.title
  btn.appendChild(caption)
})
```

```html
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 1">Button Text 1</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 2">Button Text 2</button>
<button class="btn" title="Title Text 3">Button Text 3</button>
```

References:

- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [NodeList.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)
- [Document.createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [Node.textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)
- [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyGrab I've added another example of how you can do this purely with CSS (no JS / jQuery required at all)

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
$("button").attr('title', function(i, v) {
  $(this).siblings(".title").html(v);
})
```

```css
.group {
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="group">
  <button class="btn" title="Title Text 1">Button 1</button>
  <span class="title"></span>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <button class="btn" title="Title Text 2">Button 2</button>
  <span class="title"></span>
</div>
<div class="group">
  <button class="btn" title="Title Text 3">Button 3</button>
  <span class="title"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is an interesting alternative. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem @JeremyGrab. Curious as to why I'm getting down-voted though..